# Scipy won't import in python program

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've installed scipy package with wheel distribution but as I import it in my program this error appears,

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721713/importerror-cannot-import-name-ccallback-c you can follow the developments there.

Comment: Also, what is the version of SciPy? Please add the output of the following command to the question `python3 -c 'import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)'`?