# SciPy ImportError, cannot import name '_ccallback_c'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, python-3.5

so I used pip v19.1.1 to install SciPy on my Raspberry Pi 3(B) running Raspbian Strech.
The installation was successful and when I tried to `import scipy`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

I haven't been able to find any solutions else where, including stack exchange where there is a [quetsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721713/importerror-cannot-import-name-ccallback-c) with the same issue, but since I'm using a raspberry pi, maybe the cause would be different? I've tried all the answers over there too but none of them worked :( 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name '\_ccallback\_c'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721713/importerror-cannot-import-name-ccallback-c)

Comment: I've edited with an explanation