# python 3 cython compiled files extension

Tags: cython, python-3.7

I am recompiling some cython files in python 3.7 that I was used to compile with python 2.7.x  For some reasons I ignore, compiled files are now ending with .cpython-37m-darwin.so instead of .so simply.

any explanation for that ? can i avoid having this extra .cpython-37m-darwin

thanks

Comment: This suffix is a good thing, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147. You should not avoid but embrace it.

Comment: I've added a proper answer to [this older question that asks the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986789/why-cython-compiler-generates-a-so-with-suffix-cpython-35m-x86-64-linux-gnu-so) in the hope of making it a duplicate target.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why Cython compiler generates a so with suffix 'cpython-35m-x86\_64-linux-gnu.so'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986789/why-cython-compiler-generates-a-so-with-suffix-cpython-35m-x86-64-linux-gnu-so)