# How to build a PEP384-compliant Python extension module and package it with correct ABI3 tag?

Tags: python, c, setuptools, distutils, distutils2

mymodule.c starts as follows:

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#define Py_LIMITED_API 0x03070000 
#include "Python.h"
```

It builds with no errors and warnings. Yet, the resulting file is named

```
mymodulename.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Build command:

```
$ python setup.py build
```

When I issue instead

```
$ pip wheel .
```

the extension contained in the wheel is named the same, and consequently the wheel has no ABI3 tag either.

I expected a file-name with abi3 or alike, as set out in PEP 425.

My research so far was frustrating. I looked at PEPs 384 and 425, the docs and relevant tutorials on docs.python.org, in particular its C/API and distutils, the docs from PYPA, those on setuptools, wheel and pip - to no avail.

The file /modules/xxmodule.c contained in the current Python source distro is merely of historical interest.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the backend; not all build backends support PEP 384.

#### `distutils`

For example, when using pure `distutils` (so

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(...)
```

), there's no way to change the extension suffix; this is why I had to ask the question [Change Cython's naming rules for .so files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38523941/2650249) some years ago. But you shouldn't be using pure `distutils` nowadays anyway, so this section is just for the sake of completeness.

#### `setuptools`

If you are using `setuptools`, you have to pass `py_limited_api=True` when creating `Extension` objects. Example:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension


setup(
    ...,
    ext_modules=[
        # this extension will have the SOABI suffix, e.g.
        # cpython-37m-darwin or cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu etc.
        Extension("foo", ["foo.c"]),
        # this extension will have the `abi3.so` suffix
        Extension("bar", ["bar.c"], py_limited_api=True),
    ],
)
```

#### `setuptools_rust`

Bonus: If you are building extension modules from Rust code and happen to use `setuptools_rust`, building PEP 384-compliant extensions is now also possible since v0.11.4:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools_rust import RustExtension


setup(
    ...,
    rust_extensions=[
        RustExtension("foo.rust", py_limited_api=True, features=["pyo3/abi3"]),
    ],
)
```

#### `pip wheel`: building the correct wheel tag

> When I issue
>
> ```
> $ pip wheel .
> ```
>
> the extension contained in the wheel is named the same, and consequently the wheel has no ABI3 tag either.

The wheel tag is a somewhat different story; it is independent from the extension names it packages. To set the limited ABI, when building a wheel the usual way, one would issue

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel --py-limited-api=cp37
```

The resulting wheel would then have the name `<pkg>-<ver>-cp37-abi3-<platform>.whl`.

However, this won't work with `pip wheel` as you can't pass options to the `bdist_wheel` subcommand. You can thus persist it in the `setup.cfg`:

```
# setup.cfg
[bdist_wheel]
py_limited_api = cp37
```

When running `pip wheel .` now, `bdist_wheel` will pick up the option from the `setup.cfg` and assemble the correct wheel name.